# Cookies are not being set for '.amazonaws.com' in chrome 57 and 58 browsers

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, amazon-ec2

Cookies are not being set for 'amazonaws.com' and sub-domains after upgrading to chrome 57 or 58.
Earlier it used to work fine.

Following is a test file in one of the EC2 instance, which sets a cookie in browser for domain '.amazonaws.com'.
But, the cookie is never set. (Note: we access the EC2 public DNS which is a host in amazonaws.com)

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/",     ".amazonaws.com"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

But when we set the cookie with our domain '.company.com', and accessed via our subdomain DNS. Cookie are being set there.

This behaviour of cookie not being set happened only after upgrading to chrome 57 or 58.

Any pointer on COOKIE specific changes to chrome updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior seems correct on the part of Chrome.

[This WontFix/WorkingAsIntended bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=692655) -- about another (non-AWS) domain -- references [this change in Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d81b12d08c29a8a6d8d9434d4d1d2d0c14230d53%5E%21/#F0) -- which seems, in turn, to correlate with [this change](https://github.com/publicsuffix/list/commit/7484355b7842c471e17f5c257a4833d1d50e2bf4) to the [Public Suffix List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List)... a change which added `*.compute-1.amazonaws.com` and its peers in other AWS regions to the list.

Previously, `compute-1.amazonaws.com` was on the list without a wildcard in front.

This change should effectively prevent setting cookies on (e.g.) `ec2-203-0-113-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com`... which, if you think about it, makes no sense as a practice anyway, because...

**`ec2-203-0-113-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com` is not a hostname in a domain that is yours.**

It's just a forward/reverse DNS entry for an IP address that, today, happens to be assigned to you.  How long it will be allocated to you may be a short time or a long time, but for all anyone knows, five minutes from now you could stop using it and it could be assigned to someone else, and any browser visiting what they thought was your site would dutifully hand over its cookies to whatever server happens to be listening on that address, tomorrow... potentially creating a neat exploit vector.

If you need to set cookies from your EC2 instances, you should point hostnames from your own domain to those instances.

Comment: Thanks Michael! That answered the question. I ran few other experiments confirming it.